# Visual Studio watch variable values when an unhandled exception occurs

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Is it possible to see which is the current value of a certain variable (let's say variable `r`, which is an int in my case) through the Watch in Visual Studio when an exception occurs?

My problem is that I can't access Watch when there is an exception, it would be nice to see what was the last value of my variable when the exception occured simply by looking at the Watch or something like that.

Comment: *"I can't access Watch when there is an exception"* - why is that?

Comment: Place a breakpoint before exception throwing code.

Comment: -- Console.WriteLine("Value of r: " + r);
prior to the exception happening. 

Put in a breakpoint and look at the value in watch then. The issue is, exceptions force you out of the scope you are in. Even if you put a try catch around your code, the code will escape the scope into the "catch" scope, and you won't be able to view any values that exist within the try. but you could make the declaration of "r" outside the try scope, than you can still watch it in watch, after an exception has occured.

Comment: You might want to change the exception settings to break when the exception occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Console.WriteLine("Value of r: " + r);
prior to the exception happening.

Put in a breakpoint and look at the value in watch then. The issue is, exceptions force you out of the scope you are in. Even if you put a try catch around your code, the code will escape the scope into the "catch" scope, and you won't be able to view any values that exist within the try.

But you could make the declaration of "r" outside the try scope, than you can still watch it in watch, after an exception has occured.

if you do something like this, you should be able to see your r value outside the exception.

```
public void SomeMethodThatFiddlesWithR() {
    
    int r = 0;
    
        try {
           r = int.MaxValue;
           throw new Exception("WEEEE");
        } catch (Exception exc)
        {
           Console.WriteLine("We expect the value of r to be 2147483647: Value is: " + r);
        }
        
        }
```

Comment: VS has powerful debugger with stack trace, locals, auto-variables (including returns), etc. *Usually* (*always*?) nothing else is required. OP didn't provide enough details, but in your case exception is *handled*, that's different and moreover there are planty of topics of how to stop debugger for handled exception. No need for snapshotting value.

Comment: I know in this example I am not doing anything with the exception, mostly because it was only supposed to show the value of r being retained outside the scope of try.
You should always implement a catch that handles the exception from a program point of view. If you don't, you are going to have some really late debugging evenings. doing forensics on systems that don't do anything on exceptions especially in low-level components, is going to suck. :) 
The example was just to show, that if you retain the reference, your catch scope, will be able to access the last value state a variable was in